# After Ubuntu Update, Can’t Login (GUI or Console)

Tags: login, fsck

I’m running Ubuntu 18.04 and tried updating the OD earlier today. During the reboot, a bunch of “systemd-journals: failed to write entry” started scrolling showing up on my screen.

Now, the GUI doesn’t show up at all. When I hit CTRL+ALT+F3 to access a console screen, it allows me to login and it accepts my credentials, but it returns right back to the login screen.

I’ve tried running deck from recovery mode to see if there are any file system errors, but it fails to rub because /dev/sda9 is mounted.

Any ideas?